# Json строку распарсить в массив в php

Tags: php, ajax, json

На сервере при помощи аякса получаю json строку вида:

```
[
    {
        "original_name":"Penguins.jpg",
        "serverurl":"upload/images/51528167ef67370933c5b95eed605d60.jpg"
    },    
    {
        "original_name":"Tulips.jpg",
        "serverurl":"upload/images/216f59417d2a304a1e5604ec070007fa.jpg"
    }
]
```

нужно распарсить ее в массив json_decode() не помогает.Подскажите что не так?

Comment: В jquery объект преобразую в строку и отправляю через аякс:

Comment: $('form').submit(function() {
    data = JSON.stringify(phpses);
        $.ajax({
        url:'http://proproject/main/default/post',
        type:'POST',
        data:'data='+phpses+$(this).serialize(),
         success: function(data){
            alert(data);
         }
    });
});

Comment: Все дополнения к вопросу следует вносить непосредственно в вопрос. Достаточно его отредактировать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> json_decode() не помогает.

Почему не помогает, если очень даже помогает?

```
$data = '[{"original_name":"Penguins.jpg","serverurl":"upload/images/51528167ef67370933c5b95eed605d60.jpg"},{"original_name":"Tulips.jpg","serverurl":"upload/images/216f59417d2a304a1e5604ec070007fa.jpg"}]';
$json = json_decode( $data, true );
print_r( $json );
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [original_name] => Penguins.jpg
            [serverurl] => upload/images/51528167ef67370933c5b95eed605d60.jpg
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [original_name] => Tulips.jpg
            [serverurl] => upload/images/216f59417d2a304a1e5604ec070007fa.jpg
        )
)
```

Comment: Я то же самое делаю но почему-то не превращает в массив я не знаю что делать по идее так и должно быть как у тебя((((

Comment: @СабирГоджаев, полный код что делается на сервере с полученными данными - в ответ.

Comment: if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {            $array = $_POST['data'];
            $array = json_decode($array,true);
            return json_encode($array[0]); возвращает null

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема переменная csrf валидации тоже передается через $_POST['data'];

Comment: На сервере выполнил             return json_encode($_POST['data']); и вернуло "[{\"original_name\":\"Hydrangeas.jpg\",\"serverurl\":\"upload\/images\/1423d962d3c652498ac4e4ddbaa79732.jpg\"},{\"original_name\":\"Jellyfish.jpg\",\"serverurl\":\"upload\/images\/9a0622af97a04a927a4af5c1f94dae0e.jpg\"}]_csrf=Y1FxYVNpUnckFR45PSViEAtnABkZUGUmCSIGCBRROkQUOUAuAFEaIg=="

Comment: Как распарсить на сервере этот массив ?